# Counting function in R

Tags: r, statistics

I have a dataset like this

```
id <- 1:12
b <- c(0,0,1,2,0,1,1,2,2,0,2,2)
c <- rep(NA,3)
d <- rep(NA,3)

df <-data.frame(id,b)
newdf <- data.frame(c,d)
```

I want to do simple math. If x==1 or x==2 count them and write how many 1 and 2 are there in this dataset. But I don't want to count whole dataset, I want my function count them four by four.

I want to a result like this:

```
> newdf
  one two
1   1   1
2   2   1
3   0   3
```

I tried this with lots of variation but I couldn't success.

```
afonk <- function(x) {
  ifelse(x==1 | x==2, x, newdf <- (x[1]+x[2]))
} 

afonk(newdf$one)

lapply(newdf, afonk)
```

Thanks in advance!

ismail

Comment: What do you mean by "four by four"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fun with base R:

```
# counting function
countnum <- function(x,num){
  sum(x == num)
}

# make list of groups of 4
df$group <- rep(1:ceiling(nrow(df)/4),each = 4)[1:nrow(df)]
dfl <- split(df$b,f = df$group)

# make data frame of counts
newdf <- data.frame(one = sapply(dfl,countnum,1),
                    two = sapply(dfl,countnum,2))
```

Edit based on comment:

```
# make list of groups of 4
df$group <- rep(1:ceiling(nrow(df)/4),each = 4)[1:nrow(df)]

table(subset(df, b != 0L)[c("group", "b")])
```

Which you prefer depends on what type of result you need. A table will work for a small visual count, and you can likely pull the data out of the table, but if it is as simple as your example, you might opt for the data.frame.

Comment: `sapply(, countnum)` can be replaced by `table`. After creating the "group", one approach could be `table(subset(df, b != 0L)[c("group", "b")])`

Answer (score 2):

We could use `dcast` from `data.table`.  Create a grouping variable using `%/%` and then `dcast` from 'long' to 'wide' format.

```
library(data.table)
dcast(setDT(df)[,.N ,.(grp=(id-1)%/%4+1L, b)],
      grp~b, value.var='N', fill =0)[,c(2,4), with=FALSE]
```

---

Or a slightly more compact version would be using `fun.aggregate` as `length`.

```
res <- dcast(setDT(df)[,list((id-1)%/%4+1L, b)][b!=0], 
                    V1~b, length)[,V1:=NULL][]
res
#   1 2
#1: 1 1
#2: 2 1
#3: 0 3
```

If we need the column names to be 'one', 'two'

```
library(english)
names(res) <- as.character(english(as.numeric(names(res))))
```